# XSSFWorkbook problem with tomcat but working in jboss

Tags: java, excel

i am using poi 3.16 jar for excel write when i am using it on jboss and jdk 8 it's working but now i have upgraded to tomcat 9 and jdk 8 it is not working it is giving error in servlet  to line wb.write(fileOut);

jars needed for this

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask